# Forbid Flow to Split in Flow Network

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-optimization, network-flow

Is it possible to somehow assert that flows are not allowed to split in flow networks by design? Assume you have a sink $s$ and a incoming flow value of 10. Furthermore you have 3 nodes $v_1, v_2, v_3$. I want to be the incoming flow in each node $v_i$ to be either $0$ or $5$ and nothing in between. Can this be modelled by somehow by designing a suitable network?

Many thanks.

[Here is a small sketch of the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIOIL.png)

Comment: you mean that nodes have at most one of their out-going edges with non-negative flow?

Comment: This would be a good start, yes. I know its possible for flow value of 1 of course, but how about bigger flow values?

Comment: If you could solve non-splitting network flow, I believe you could solve 3-SAT via a flow reduction by sending flow to each variable (represented as a node), splitting the flow along the term of it and its negation, and then directing them to clauses which are capacitated to unity flow?

Answer (score -1):

Let the flow variable be $x_{ij}$, introduce a binary variable $y_{ij}$, and impose linear constraint $x_{ij}=5y_{ij}$.

Comment: I guess the point of mentioning "by design" means the author wants to apply the usual polynomial algorithms for network flows.

Comment: @Qise This “no split” requirement destroys total unimodularity, so preserving  polynomial time should not be expected.